# How to bind remote JSON data to a Polymer vaadin-grid?

Tags: polymer-1.0, vaadin-grid

First time using this web component... I'm able to bind JSON data in a var to a vaadin-grid (w/ polymer 1.0), but am missing something basic about getting the JSON data from a url into the grid.

Here's the most simple example I could create, that worked with hard-coded JSON and now have used some of the examples from the Vaadin website to attempt to pull the data from a URL.

```
 <head> 
//  import statements same as in my example that works with hard coded JSON
  <script>
  function getJSON(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
        callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
          }
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
       xhr.send();
     }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Vaadin Grid - example </h2><br>
  <vaadin-grid selection-mode="multi">
    <table>
   <col name="name">
   <col name="city">
   </table>
  </vaadin-grid>

<script>
  var grid = grid || document.querySelector('vaadin-grid');

  HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
    grid.items = function(params, callback) {
      var url = 'https://.../simple-data.json';
      getJSON(url, function(data) {
        callback(data[0]);
      });
    }; 
 });
</script>
```

And simple-data.json URL returns this:

```
[ { "name": "Jose Romero", "city": "Monteray" }, { "name": "Chuy Diez", "city": "Los Angeles" }, { "name": "Inez Vega", "city": "San Diego" } ]
```

Where am I going wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question again: to bind JSON to a vaadin-grid using JavaScript instead of using the Polymer iron-ajax component simply add this script section to the bottom of the body.  It adds an event listener for WebComponentsReady.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
  var grid = document.querySelector('vaadin-grid');
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        grid.items = json;
      }
     }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://<your_url>', true);
    xhr.send();
 });
</script>
```

For others getting started with vaadin Polymer components they have a series of very short, but excellent tutorials -  search YouTube for "vaadin elementary school" to find them.

Answer (score 0):

Binding is easily done using the Polymer 1.0 iron-ajax component.  Here's the working code:

```
<head> 
//  import statements same as in my example that works with hard coded JSON
 <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
 <link rel="import" href="vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid.html">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Vaadin Grid - working example </h2><br>
  <template is="dom-bind">
    <iron-ajax 
      auto
      url = "http://hostname/.../simple-data.json"
      handle-as="json"
      last-response="{{gridData}}" ></iron-ajax>
    <vaadin-grid selection-mode="multi" items="{{gridData}}">
      <table>
        <col name="name">
        <col name="city">
      </table>
    </vaadin-grid>
  </template>
 <script>
 </script>
</body>
```

I still would like to learn how it's done using the JavaScript code in the Vaadin documentation [Remote Data](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/elements/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid-lazy-loading.html#vaadin-grid.lazy-loading.remote)   Any tips?